# What is the limit on QueryString / GET / URL parameters

Tags: http, query-string

What is the limit on QueryString / GET / URL parameters

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is no limit in theory. For HTTP URLs, the [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.1) states:

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
> a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
> serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
> provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
> SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
> than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).

But in practice, many clients and servers do only support URLs up to a certain length. The [rule of thumb is not to use URLs longer than 2000 characters](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019132547/http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) (percent encoding already taken into account).

Comment: Do you know a list of major (often used) components that have this limit?

Comment: @Thomas No, unfortunately not.

Comment: The linked article is a great (although dated) overview of how different browsers/sytems handle this.

Comment: The linked article is linking to a loans website and is completely irrelevant
Edit: appears the domain was bought / taken over late last year

Comment: Updated the link to the web archive version

Answer (score 5):

There is no defined limit. However, RFC 2068 states:

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15). Note: Servers should be cautious about depending on URI lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations may not properly support these lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Although officially there is no limit specified by RFC 2616, many security protocols and recommendations state that maxQueryStrings on a server should be set to a maximum character limit of 1024. While the entire URL, including the querystring, should be set to a max of 2048 characters. This is to prevent the Slow HTTP Request DDOS vulnerability on a web server. This typically shows up as a vulnerability on the Qualys Web Application Scanner and other security scanners.

Please see the below exampple code for Windows IIS Servers with Web.config:

This would also work on a server level using machine.config.

Note: Limiting query string and URL length may not completely prevent Slow HTTP Requests DDOS attack but it is one step you can take to prevent it.