# What is the maximum allowable size of an image in HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using HttpWebRequest to post an image in server in windows phone application, what is the maximum image size which i can send in this way??
Will it lead to problems in some cases??

Comment: Here's the summary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557663/is-there-a-limit-on-the-size-of-a-http-argument-value-in-a-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST size is limited by the Server. For IIS it s `maxReceivedMessageSize=""`. The limitations in your app is more likely given by the current network, your youser is conected to.  If you handle big images, you have to deal with deactivtion and reactivation of the app, during your post request. Windows Phone itself provides a best practice for [background file transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286419%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

if you are in the position to  negotiate the server interface, this approach is highly recommended