# Stopping PHP script putting URL's in address bar?

Tags: php

I have a script that pulls in meta data from a list of URL's but when I try to out too many it it says URL is too long and wont run.

My question is how can I stop this from happening?

```
<?php
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
function parseUrl($url){
    //Trim whitespace of the url to ensure proper checking.
    $url = trim($url);
    //Check if a protocol is specified at the beginning of the url. If it's not,   prepend 'http://'.
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    //Check if '/' is present at the end of the url. If not, append '/'.
    if (substr($url, -1)!=="/"){
            $url .= "/";
    }
    //Return the processed url.
    return $url;
}
//If the form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['siteurl'])){
    //Put every new line as a new entry in the array
    $urls = explode("\n",trim($_GET["siteurl"]));
    //Iterate through urls
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
            //Parse the url to add 'http://' at the beginning or '/' at the end if not   already there, to avoid errors with the get_meta_tags function
            $url = parseUrl($url);
            //Get the meta data for each url
            $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
            //Check to see if the description tag was present and adjust output   accordingly
            $tags = NULL;
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
if($tags)
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>" .$tags['description']. "</td></tr>";
else 
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>No Meta Description</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's good that you're commenting, but don't comment over every little line! "Iterate through url" That much is obvious from the code itself!

Comment: GET method is not really for LONG data. Use POST instead.

Comment: Thanks! And ok I'll limit my commenting ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then POST the URL's. GET is [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091485/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring-get-url-parameters).