# Can't Upload Large String to Server

Tags: android, string

I am trying to upload a string to server by post.. This is my code..

```
String URL = "http://myUrl/add?user_id="+user_id
        + "&text=" + text 
        + "&type=" + type;

URL = URL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
URL = URL.replaceAll("\n", "%0A");
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is working when i am uploading a small string.. but when i am trying to send large string (more than 2 lines) for example.. it doesn't work..
Any suggestions?

Thank you :)

Comment: Get Max Char limit is `256` Use Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Method **Get** has Maximium Chars limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3091523/1008278), instead Use **Post**

```
String URL = "http://myUrl/add";
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", text));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I can't give you +1 :( it's required 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\"` to send a string:

```
String URL = "myUrl/add?user_id="+user_id 
+ "\"&text=\"" + text 
+ "\"&type=\"" + type;
```

Also you should use `POST` instead `GET`

Answer (score 0):

You transfer your data as part of the query string, which is part of the URL. There is a maximum length on URLs which depends heavily on the client and server software. As far as I know there is no standard which defines this maximum.

Anyways, you should transfer a large amount of data in the HTTP request body. See [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use NameValuePair for sending the data, you are using HTTP POST to send the data in GET Style. I will strongly recommend use of NameValuePair to send the data.A small example is
`List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","email"));
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();`