# Dynamic Pages routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

The question seems realy simple, but I can't figure it out... How do you achieve slug-based dynamic pages with categories in Laravel 5.1?

Something like `mywebsite.com/category/sub-category/my-page`

I know that `Route::get('/{slug}')` gives the "slug" as identifier, but the problem is that the page could be situated in `mywebsite.com/category/my-page`, so if set the route to something like `Route::get('/{category}/{subcategory}/{page}')` it will not work for the second example.

I was thinking about making 3 routes like

```
Route::get('/{category}/{subcategory}/{page}')
Route::get('/{category}/{page}')
Route::get('/{page}')
```

And then the controller to receive `($category = null, $subcategory = null, $page = null)`
And in the controller something like

```
if (!$page)
    $page = $subcategory;

if (!$page)
    $page = $category;
```

Is there another, cleaner way to achieve this? Because here we have only 2 category routes, but there could be 3, 5 or more?

Comment: This seems like the product of poor design.  If you don't need the category and subcategory to show a page, don't force your users to go through it.  If you are somehow stuck with these routes, use `request()->page` to get the page rather than fumble with the function parameters.

Comment: i wonder if you could use `Route::controller` with a *dynamic* method like, `public function getSomePage(Request $request)` then do a manual approach over `$request->segments()` - didn't tried this, nevertheless, reading [the doc](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) might give some insight. **ps.** `route::controller` although having a predefined parameter, ie. `getSomePage($category, $slug)` in `route::list` still being shown as `SomePage/{one?}/{two?}/.../{five?}`

Comment: @Ivan Milanovm , if use `Route::get('/{page}')` how show other url? example `/user` or ... the urls that not `page` .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you want to have a categories of categories and able to access posts through those categories. I assume you had a model like this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
  public function SubCategories()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
  }
  public function ParentCategory()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id', 'id);
  }
  public function Page()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Page', 'category_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

then on create a controller to retrieve posts

```
class PageLoaderController extends Controller
{
   //assumes you want to run this via root url (/)
   public function getIndex(Requests $request)
   {
     //this practically get you any parameter after public/ (root url)
     $categories = $request->segments();
     $countSeg   = count($categories);
     $fcategory  = null;
     $fpage      = null;
     for($i = 0; $i < $countSeg; $i++)
     {
       //this part of iteration is hypothetical - you had to try it to make sure it had the desired outcome
       if(($i + 1) == $countSeg)
       {
         //make sure fcategory != null, it should throw 404 otherwise
         //you had to add code for that here
         $fpage = $fcategory->Page()->where('slug', $categories[$i])->firstOrFail();
       }
       elseif($i == 0)
       {
         //find initial category, if no result, throw 404
         $fcategory = Category::where('slug', $categories[0])->firstOrFail();
       }
       else
       {
         //take it's child category if possible, otherwise throw 404
         $fcategory = $fcategory->SubCategories()->where('slug', $categories[$i])->firstOrFail()
       }
     }
     //do something with your $fpage, render it or something else
   }
}
```

Then add to your `route.php`:

```
Route::controller('/','PageLoaderController', [
                  'getIndex' => 'home'
                  ]);
```

That should do. However, this is a *dirty* approach which is i won't suggest using this thing extensively. Some of the reasons are, [http get length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091485/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring-get-url-parameters) is not limited but it's a bad practice to have it too long, this approach is not good for CRUD - go for `Route::resource` instead, also the loop looks painful.

**Take note**: `Route::controller` is more wild than `Route::resource` you had to put entries in `route.php` in this order `Route::<http verb>`, `Route::resource` then finally `Route::controller`. So far, i faced Laravel route behavior, it'll poke `Route::controller` even if it had no method regarding requested url and throws a `NotFoundHttpException`. So if you had `Route::<http verb>` after `Route::controller` laravel tend to not touch it at all.