# Maximum url query string too many different opinions?

Tags: firebase, http, url, server

I am reading conflict information here.

I would like to return from server to client some url query  such as :

```
domain.com/page/varA=1&varB=link&varC=link2... ...
```

I read here that the max length for this url is **2000** characters :
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

and here that its **8Kb** (which is much much more than 2000 chars)

[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

This one says **60-80K** characters for all browsers

[What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

This one says **2000** but point to a link that says **80000**.
[What is the limit on QueryString / GET / URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091485/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring-get-url-parameters)

and basically every Google search provide a different value.

I guess i am confusing between things here, but **2000 chars are  0.002 MB**.
The server I use to return it is `Firebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length of a URL that can be processed by Firebase Hosting is 8KiB (8,192 bytes).

Browsers / HTTP clients may have more restrictive limitations, but Firebase Hosting will allow URLs up to 8KiB.

Comment: Thanks Michael,  in practice, do you think it would be a good practice for me to return a url of around 3000 characters from Firebase to Chrome+Safari , on mobile? it will make things 70% faster for me, and i wonder if it is ok.

Comment: I think up to 4K is probably okay in most browsers, but I can't say with absolute certainty.